# ReverGeoCodeLocation result in Other Language

Tags: google-maps, swift3, xcode8

I am using this code to get the current location information(Country - City...etc) from Google API
My question is how can I get the result country name in Arabic or any other language?

please help

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Geocoding
//
//  Created by Moaaz Nash on 5/29/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Moaaz Nash. All rights reserved.
//

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6.0)
            let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
            view = mapView

            mapView.delegate = self
            mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true


            if let mylocation = mapView.myLocation {
                print("User's location: \(mylocation)")
            } else {
                print("User's location is unknown")
            }

            var longitude :CLLocationDegrees = 46.736228
            var latitude :CLLocationDegrees = 24.756455

            var location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) //changed!!!
            print(location)

            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                print(location)

                if error != nil {
                    print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                    return
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mention in official document of `Google Maps APIs`here : [How can I get the Google Maps APIs to display in a language other than English?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport)

> By default the API will attempt to load the most appropriate language based on the users location or browser settings. Some APIs allow you to explicitly set a language when you make a request.

So you directly can't change language because its depends on your device language or browser settings.